# Same record returned when calling stored proc

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a mysql db (I will also need this to run against MSSQL later though) with a stored proc called aa_acme_consumables which takes a serial number parameter.  I can call it in mysql as follows:

```
call aa_acme_consumables("12345");
```

and I will the following records returned:

```
Serial_No | partID | Qty | Description
12345     | a123   | 10  | Widget One
12345     | b456   | 3   | Widget Two
```

Full disclosure: I may have parts of different solutions confused during my many attempts.  Here is what I have so far.

My **@Entity class** looks as follows:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Consumable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Serial_No")
    private String serialNo;
    @Column(name = "partID")
    private String partID;
    @Column(name = "Qty")
    private int quantity;
    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String desc;    
}
```

My **Repository class** look as follows"

```
@Repository
public interface ConsumableRepo extends JpaRepository<Consumable, Integer>, ConsumableRepoCust { }
```

My **Custom Repository Class** look like this:

```
public interface ConsumableRepoCust {
    public List<Consumable> getAllConsumables(String serialNum); 
}
```

My **Repository Implementation** looks as follows:

```
public class ConsumableRepoImpl {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
    
    public List<Consumable> getAllConsumables(String serialNum) throws SQLException {
        
        StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("xx_bds_Consumable", Consumable.class);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("serialNum", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.setParameter("serialNum", serialNum);
        
        query.execute();
        
        List<Consumable> consumableList = query.getResultList();
        
        for (Consumable c : consumableList ) {
            System.out.println("Description : " + c.getDesc() );
        }
                
        return consumableList ;
    }
}
```

I am expecting to have the following returned:

```
========== ABOUT TO RUN STORED PROC ==========
Hibernate: {call aa_acme_consumables(?)}
Description : Widget One
Description : Widget Two
```

*So my question:*
** Why do I get this returned? **

```
========== ABOUT TO RUN STORED PROC ==========
Hibernate: {call aa_acme_consumables(?)}
Description : Widget One
Description : Widget One
```

I am expecting to get the description from the 2nd record (Widget Two) returned just like when I call the stored proc from mysql but instead I am getting Widget One twice.  This has been doing my head in.

Comment: Not sure if this is the root issue, but `Serial_No` is not unique in the example results so it should probably not be marked as `@Id`.  Perhaps `PartId` should be the `@Id`?

Comment: You guys never cease to amaze me ... Thank you so much.  I changed the @Id to the Description (which should be unique for this test) and I go the results I expected.